# Submenu in submenu using ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hello i'm trying to do a submenu in a submenu using ui-route. Im trying to do something like this in angular v1.

->folders

---->jobs

------->coder

------->chef

folder it's a menu, jobs it's a sub menu and coder and chef it's the options that are inside of the submenu of coder

here is my code

```
$stateProvider
.state('folders', {
url: '/app/folders',
template : '',
abstract: true,
controller: "foldersCTRL",
 title: 'Folders',
  sidebarMeta: {
    icon: 'ion-grid',
    order: 1,
  },
}).state('jobs', {
  url: '/jobs',
  abstract: true,
  title: 'Jobs',
})
.state('jobs.coder', {
  parent: 'jobs',
  url: '/coder',
  title: 'Coder',
  sidebarMeta: {
    order: 0,
  },
}).state('jobs.chef', {
  parent: 'chef',
  url: '/jobs',
  title: 'Chef',
  sidebarMeta: {
    order: 0,
  },
});
}
```

but that code only show me something like this

```
->folders
--->jobs
--->coder
--->chef
```

any idea or sugestion to do a submenu in submenu using ui-route?

Comment: Is this AngularJS (ie Angular v1)? If so, please use the "AngularJS" tag. The "Angular" tag is now for Angular V2.

Comment: it's angular v1 sorry.

Comment: No problem. Just trying to ensure you get the correct "eyes" on it. :-)

Comment: how it's shown is not related to the how you define your routes, you need to show us actual html parts where you render the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You've to make changes in state names. Make it like `folders`, `folders.jobs`, `jobs.coder`, `jobs.chef` respectively and also remove parent property from coder & chef state. Careful with using parent property, it should have value just what you defined as in state name with dot notification (so for last one parent should be jobs if your statename is jobs.chef).

Checkout this plunker for similar nested view implementation: https://plnkr.co/edit/F5Upm3EsjD40QQ1E3Nwx?p=preview

Also if you're defining your state as abstract then it need to have only ui-view tag element in template, because that's where its child states gonna load.
Checkout this plunker for that: http://plnkr.co/edit/gmtcE2?p=preview

Also take a look at [ui-router official documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) where the ways & structure for nested view implementation explained.